# How do you position text on footer directly under each other?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how position my text on footer directly under each other in three different column

right now only the left column is good the center and the right column are broken

[image]

```css
.footer {
  /* The dividing footer: */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #efebe785;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #00000094;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
  top: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="left">
      <font size="5">SOCIAL</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Facebook </font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3"> Twitter </font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3"> Youtube </font>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="right">
      <font size="5">EXTRA</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Our Chefs</font>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <p class="centered">
      <font size="5">SUPPORT</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Tellphone</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Email</font>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text isn't aligned correctly in the `center` and `right` columns because they have the text alignment of `center` and `right` instead of `left`.

Rather than building your columns using text alignment, you can set them all to be a third of the parent's width, and give them all left-aligned text. See the following snippet.

```css
.footer {
  /* The dividing footer: */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #efebe785;
  color: #000000;
  /* Align all the text left so it lines up */
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #00000094;
}

/* Build 3 equal-width columns inside the footer */
.left, 
.right, 
.center {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="left">
      <font size="5">SOCIAL</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Facebook </font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3"> Twitter </font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3"> Youtube </font>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="right">
      <font size="5">EXTRA</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Our Chefs</font>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <p class="center">
      <font size="5">SUPPORT</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Tellphone</font> <br/><br/>
      <font size="3">Email</font>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: font tag is no more supported, so maybe remove them and warn OP about :)

Comment: and why you make all the alignement to the left ? am sure the op want it to be left - center -right

Comment: @TemaniAfif Read the question to know why she aligned them to the left. This is the correct answer and I was typing a similar answer but got distracted before posting it. As to your first comment, you probably meant to say **deprecated** (in HTML 4.01) or **obsolete** (in HTML5). That's completely different from **supported** because it is still supported in all browsers as far as I know. I agree that we should avoid using it, but it will still be supported for a long time.

Comment: @RacilHilan yes the word is not good, but that what i meant .. i also write it to may answer ;) and i read the question and don't see something related to left alignment ...

Comment: @RacilHilan by the way, it's supported by some browser but when you read over the internet you will also see the word not supported for HTML5 :http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/tags/html5_font.asp.htm  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: @TemaniAfif I could be wrong, because the wording is not clear, but to me **position my text on footer directly under each other** with no further instructions means to left-align them. Also if you look at the result of this answer and compare it to the other answers (like yours), which one do you think looks better and more likely to be the intended result? Again, I might be wrong, so the OP will choose.

Comment: @RacilHilan sure i totally agree .. but my logic was the use of `text-align` inside each one so i supposed he want different alignement for each box. If not why use them ? so let the OP decide :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Which browser does not support the `font` tag? I don't know of any and I think they all will continue to support it for a long time. Also just because the word supported is used somewhere doesn't make it right (now somebody in the future will refer to your comment and think the word is fine :-) ). However, I wouldn't have complained if you said *HTML5 doesn't support it*, that's OK, but you said *no more supported* which implies that it is not supported by the browsers, which is incorrect.

Comment: @RacilHilan i agree with this and my intention was to say `HTML5 doesn't support it,` but in a shorter way ... in all the cases (supported or not) we should avoid them :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have a list of items, it's a very good practice to use `<li></li>` tag. In this case, you have links, and for link destination, you should use `<a href="#"></a>`. Each `HTML Tag` is created for a specific purpose.

And, for the `columns layout`, I have used `CSS Grid Layout`.
`Grid Layout` its very powerful, it helps you to organize your layout in many different ways. You just have to specify to a parent element `display: grid;`, and add here how you want to display columns. In our case, we have three columns, and these columns have same width, so, I have added `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 20px;`

- ***Fr is a fractional unit and 1fr is for 1 part of the available space***

For a better reference, I would suggest this: [Complete Guide To CSS Grid System](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Hope I've been clear!

Your code structure should look something like this:

```css
.footer {
  /* The dividing footer: */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #efebe785;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #00000094;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.links li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.link-item {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.link-item.centered {
 text-align: center;
}

.link-item.right-aligned {
 text-align: right;
}


.link-item a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-item a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="links">
  <div class="link-item">
  <h3>Social</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Facebook</a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Youtube</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="link-item centered">
  <h3>Support</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Tel</a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="link-item right-aligned">
  <h3>Extra</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Our Chefs</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you need to adjust the alignment ... the left is ok, but the center should be centered and the right righ aligned

Comment: now it's better, i also advice you to add more explanation on why using **li** and a tag (which is a good idea) and about the grid system ... then you answer will be perfect :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yeah, you are right, but sometimes I don't have enough time to give explanations. Anyway, I will explain my answer. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the css you need (use flex):

```
.footer{
/* The dividing footer: */
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
background-color: #efebe785;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
border:1px solid #00000094; 
display: flex;
}

.left, .center, .right{
flex-grow:1
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wxn9sp4/

Comment: why **you need** ? this is simply an alternative, he don't need this CSS, but he need to also restruct the HTML and correct his CSS and remove some obsolete tags. So you may tell him what is wrong before adding another alternative

Comment: i think this site is made for this stuff = helping people to improve by telling them what wrongs and what to correct and not simply through code that works :) if am wrong tell me